# .ics (iCAL) not opening when downloading on android. But opens from gmail

Tags: android, galaxy, icalendar

I've made a .ics file for importing events into a calendar. 
http://bcaeternitas.nl/modules/mod_blank15v52/tmpl/kalender.php?plg_ID=2469&cmp_ID=492&org_ID=4

It passes 100% validation on several ical validators online.

However, when I download it via any android browser, it downloads succesfully but I get a parse error when opening it. When I email the same file via gmail to my account, and open it on the same android device (galaxy s2), it works without a parse error.

How is this possible? Do I need to edit the code?

Answer (score 0):

android doesn't like the 'duration' property, that's why it didn't work...